# How to change the LwjglApplicationConfiguration once the application is started

Tags: java, libgdx

I am coding an application by evolutionary computation and it takes a lot of time if I render every iteration at 60fps, for this reason I have changed my DesktopLauncher this way :

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.height = 800;    
        config.width = 800;     
        config.vSyncEnabled = false; // Setting to false disables vertical sync
        //config.foregroundFPS = 60; // Setting to 60 fps throttling
        config.foregroundFPS = 0; // Setting to 0 disables foreground fps throttling
        config.backgroundFPS = 0; // Setting to 0 disables background fps throttling
        new LwjglApplication(new MyApp(), config);
    }
}
```

Now let's say; once every iterations are made, I would like my application to be limited to 60 fps (or enable V-Sync), how can I access/modify to the config?

```
public class RandomScreenClass {
  ...
  @Override
    public void render(float deltaTime) {
    if(..)
    {
     //modify the fps / turn on v-sync
    }
```

Comment: did you check this out? http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=21166#p87693 It shows you how to change the resolution on after creating the application

Comment: im also pretty sure that what you are looking for can be found in this API https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html

Comment: yes, managed to turn on V-sync again using this : Gdx.graphics.setVSync(true); But couldn't find a way to change foregroundfps/backgroundfps, that's still helping me so you can post it as an answer i guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a "fancy" way to change the LwjglConfig, I can't find a getter, but this works:

1. Create an interface with two methods in your core project, lets say setForegroundFPS and setBackgroundFPS like this:

   ```
   public interface Callback {
      void setForegroundFPS(int foregroundFPS);
      void setBackgroundFPS(int backgroundFPS);
   }
   ```
2. Add Callback as a member of your game class, and create a proper constructor to receive it

   ```
   public YourGame(Callback callback) {
      this.callback = callback;
      ...
   }
   ```
3. In your desktop project, implement the callback, like this

   ```
       public static void main(String[] arg) {
           final LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
           new LwjglApplication(new YourGame(new Callback() {
               @Override
               public void setForegroundFPS(int foregroundFPS) {
                   config.foregroundFPS = foregroundFPS;
               }

               @Override
               public void setBackgroundFPS(int backgroundFPS) {
                   config.backgroundFPS = backgroundFPS;
               }
           }), config);
       }
   ```
4. Now simply call callback.setBackgroundFPS() or callback.setForegroundFPS()

Note that I ignored vSync because its already available in:

```
    Gdx.graphics.setVSync(true);
```

Comment: that's a good turn around! I doubt there is an easier way, works like a charm thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help you, happy coding